# How to print a WMTS layer using MapFish v2 (from GeoNetwork)

Tags: printing, wmts, geonetwork, mapfish

I'm trying to configure printing from the map view in GeoNetwork 3.0.x. This seems to use MapFish version 2.1.1 (if Maven is to be believed). I have a REST WMTS layer that (after I've modified PrintMapService.js to pass the encoding correctly) seems to produce a reasonable config.json header:

```
{"layout":"A4 landscape","srs":"EPSG:27700","units":"m","rotation":0,"lang":"en","dpi":"190",
   "layers":[{
      "layer":"os_background_bng_colour",
      "opacity":1,
      "type":"WMTS",
      "baseURL":"https://xxx.xxxx.co.uk/services/xxxxxxx/wmts/os_background_bng_colour/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.png",
      "version":"1.0.0",
      "requestEncoding":"REST",
      "format":"image/png",
      "customParams":{},
      "style":"default",
      "matrixSet":"scotland_bng",
      "matrixIds":[{"identifier":"00","resolution":1000,"tileSize":[256,256],"topLeftCorner":[0,1300000],"matrixSize":[156.54303392804096,156.54303392804096]},....],
      "enableLegends":true,
      "pages":[{"center":[301200,743200],
      "scale":"500000.0",
      "dataOwner":"© ",
      "rotation":0,
      "comment":"",
      "title":"",
      "langen":true}
     ]
}
```

This gives me an error in the response:

```
org.mapfish.print.InvalidJsonValueException: spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: https://xxxx.xxxx.co.uk/services/xxxxxxx/wmts/os_background_bng_colour/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.png (Illegal character in path at index 98: https://xxxx.xxxxx.co.uk/services/xxxxxxx/wmts/os_background_bng_colour/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.png)
    at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.HTTPMapReader.<init>(HTTPMapReader.java:73)
    at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.TileableMapReader.<init>(TileableMapReader.java:42)
    at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.WMTSMapReader.<init>(WMTSMapReader.java:90)
    at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.WMTSMapReader.<init>(WMTSMapReader.java:40)
    at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.WMTSMapReader$Factory.create(WMTSMapReader.java:68)
    at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.MapReaderFactoryFinder.create(MapReaderFactoryFinder.java:36)
    at org.mapfish.print.map.MapChunkDrawer.renderImpl(MapChunkDrawer.java:129)
    at org.mapfish.print.ChunkDrawer.render(ChunkDrawer.java:55)
    at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.MapBlock$1.render(MapBlock.java:77)
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFCustomBlocks.addAbsoluteDrawer(PDFCustomBlocks.java:183)
    at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.MapBlock.render(MapBlock.java:73)
    at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Page.render(Page.java:73)
    at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.MainPage.render(MainPage.java:63)
    at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Layout.render(Layout.java:59)
    at org.mapfish.print.output.AbstractOutputFormat.doPrint(AbstractOutputFormat.java:30)
    at org.mapfish.print.output.PdfOutputFactory.print(PdfOutputFactory.java:58)
    at org.mapfish.print.MapPrinter.print(MapPrinter.java:173)
    at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doCreatePDFFile(MapPrinterServlet.java:367)
    at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.createPDF(MapPrinterServlet.java:184)
    at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doPost(MapPrinterServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.fao.geonet.monitor.webapp.WebappMetricsFilter.doFilter(WebappMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.fao.geonet.monitor.webapp.MetricsRegistryInitializerFilter.doFilter(MetricsRegistryInitializerFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(JeevesDelegatingFilterProxy.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This seems to be because `{` is not a valid character in an URI - but if I leave these elements off the end of the base URL I get a PDF back which has a scale bar but a note saying "Null Pointer Exception" in it.

The [docs](http://www.mapfish.org/doc/print/protocol.html#wmts) are a little vague on what should go in the baseURL.

has anyone managed to print a WMTS layer in MapFish v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time with the debugger and the mapfish code base I have managed to print a WMTS baselayer using the REST protocol.

First I had to modify `components/common/map/print/PrintMapService.js` to include the required optional parameters that MapFish wanted, (around line 300) - I added `dimensions` and `customParams` (I left them empty) and changed `requestEncoding` to look up the required encoding.

```
    angular.extend(enc, {
        type: 'WMTS',
        baseURL: url,
        layer: source.getLayer(),
        version: source.getVersion(),
        requestEncoding: source.getRequestEncoding() || 'KVP',
        format: source.getFormat(),
        customParams: {},
        style: source.getStyle(),
        dimensions: [],
        matrixSet: matrixSet,
        matrixIds: matrixIds
      });
```

I also had to fake out the baseURL in the `config.js` file as MapFish needs it to be URLEncoded (so `{` becomes `%7B` and `}` becomes `%7D`) but OpenLayers3 seems unable to handle this when it tries to draw the map on screen (sigh!). So I added a new `URL` field to the `ol.layer.tile` which was encoded and left the `url` in the `ol.source.WMTS` unencoded. To handle this in MapFish I modified line 289 of `components/common/map/print/PrintMapService.js` to be

```
      /*var url = layer instanceof ol.source.WMTS ?
          layer.getSource().getUrl() :
          layer.getSource().getUrls()[0];*/
      var url = layer.get('url');
```

so it picks up the urlencoded version.

The next step is to stop MapFish trying to fetch the Capabilities document from the tile URL (my WMTS server doesn't seem to support a getcapabilities request - I suspect it's broken). All that is needed is to set the (undocumented) `ignoreCapabilities` variable to true in the print-config.yaml file, just add the following line:

```
ignoreCapabilities: true
```

The final issue I ran into is that my map tiles are served over `https` and MapFish was having an issue with security certificate lookups. I solved this by switching the the "printing" url to use `http` while the OpenLayers tiles continued to get the tiles via `https`.

Comment: Hello @Ian Turton I am running into the same exact issue, but I cannot seem to find the file where I have to make MapFish get the Encoded URL, where is `components/common/map/print/PrintMapService.js` I do not see any js file with such name...in which repository of Mapfish is? I cannot see it here https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish-print/find/2.0.x